# How can I get value of the button clicked from multiple option in ionic 3

Tags: angular, button, ionic2

I have a list of multiple buttons dynamically labelled via JSON from web server, I want to identify the exact button clicked by user and display  its value in another page, here is my code:

Home.html

```
<ion-content no-padding >

      <ion-item no-padding no-lines *ngFor="let item of items" >
  <ion-card  >

      <img class="images" src="http://mydomain/{{item.poll_image}}">

    <ion-item text-wrap>
      <div class="headings">{{item.topic}}</div>
    </ion-item >

       <button ion-button  full (click)= "select(option, 'A')" >{{item.option_a}}</button> 
       <button ion-button  full  (click)= "select(option,'B')" >{{item.option_b}}</button> 
       <button ion-button  full  (click)= "select(option,'C')" >{{item.option_c}}</button> 
       <button ion-button  full  (click)= "select(option,'D')" >{{item.option_d}}</button> 

       </ion-card>
    </ion-item>

</ion-content>
```

and my .ts file

```
select(option, selection){


       this.navCtrl.push(TestPage,selection)
     }
```

I used navParams to collect the data on the TestPage, that's no problem, my challenge is how I can idenfiy the button clicked by user out of the multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `option` is here, but you can pass the `item` object and the `option_a` object to know exactly what was selected. So:

```
<button ion-button  full (click)= "select(item,  item.option_a)" >{{ item.option_a }}
</button>
```

will give you access to the item that triggered the click and the option within that item that triggered the click. Or if you want to know whether it was `A,B,C or D`

```
<button ion-button  full (click)= "select(item,  item.option_a, 'A')" >{{ item.option_a }}
</button>
```

As for communicating between components, the Angular way is to use [services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

```
select(item, option, selection) {
  this.whateverService.emitSelection(item, option);  
}
```

We can use a behavior subject to emit each change to the selection. The service would look like:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WhateverService {

  private selection = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  get selectionObservable$(){
    return this.selection.asObservable();
  }

  constructor() { }

  public emitSelection(item, option) {
    this.selection.next({ item, option });
  }

}
```

The other component would look like

```
export class WhateverComponent {

selection$: Observable;

  constructor(private whateverService: WhateverService) {
    this.selection$ = this.whateverService.selectionObservable$;
  }
}
```

and in the view, the async pipe allows for subscription:

```
<div>{{ (selection$ | async).option }}
```